# React native can‘t load Image

Tags: react-native

```
import {Thumbnail} from native-base;

https://www.shepnt.com/File/Headfaces/20180417/18041717352591516.jpg'}} />

```
I can't see image on my phone.But if I change the domain,it work well.Note This domain that "https://www.shepnt.com/"  has no anti-theft chain.Why?Who could help me

Comment: what was that previous domain in which you are facing issue ?

Comment: en，My App can't load images that on https://www.shepnt.com/

Answer (score 1):

As your question suggest your using thumbnail of native base then

```
<Thumbnail small square source={{uri: "https://www.shepnt.com/File/Headfaces/20180417/18041717352591516.jpg"}} />
```

Specify size. If want to use `Image` tag from `'react-native'`

```
<Image
      style={{width: 50, height: 50}}
      source={{uri: 'https://www.shepnt.com/File/Headfaces/20180417/18041717352591516.jpg'}}
    />
```